# Is there a ResolvedFuture class in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency, future

https://gist.github.com/2414323

Sometimes, you already know the result of a computation, but your interface requires you to return a `Future`. Rather than implement a long anonymous class, or extend AbstractFuture or FutureTask which are themselves complicated, I find it simpler to just create a small holder class that implements `Future`.

My question is - does a class similar to what I wrote below already exist in one of the standard libraries?

**Usage:**

```
Future<Boolean> iHaveToReturnAFutureButIAlreadyKnowTheAnswer() {
    return new ResolvedFuture(true);
}
```

**Code:**

```
/**
 * Used when you need to return a Future, but you already have the answer.
 */
public class ResolvedFuture<T> implements Future<T>{
    private final T item;

    public ResolvedFuture(T item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCancelled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDone() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public T get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        return item;
    }

    @Override
    public T get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        return item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard library doesn't support it, but some third-party libraries may contains such an implementation. For example, [`Futures.immediateFuture()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#immediateFuture%28V%29) from Google Guava.